# Is secure return salt data of user model?

Tags: javascript, security, encryption, hash, get

In a MEAN app i define my user model and encrypt the password using the fields hash and salt like these:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var UsersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    personalId: {
        type: String,
        unique: "Personal Id already exists",
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    surname:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: "Username already exists",
        required: "Please fill in a username",
        lowercase: true
    },
    hash: String,
    salt: String,
    email:{
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true
    },
    contract:{
        type: String
    },
    role:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    dateUpdated: {
        type: Date
    },
    dateCreated: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

UsersSchema.methods.setPassword = function (password) {
    this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64, 'sha512').toString('hex');
};

UsersSchema.methods.validPassword = function (password) {
    var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64, 'sha512').toString('hex');
    return this.hash === hash;
};

UsersSchema.methods.generateJwt = function () {
    var expiry = new Date();
    expiry.setDate(expiry.getDate() + 7);

    return jwt.sign({
        _id: this._id,
        username: this.username,
        exp: parseInt(expiry.getTime() / 1000),
    }, "MY_SECRET"); // DO NOT KEEP YOUR SECRET IN THE CODE!
};

mongoose.model('Users', UsersSchema);
```

When i create a new user, return the object user complete (all values),
when i get list of users too return all values for each user.

My question is: **Is correct return salt and hash values when i ask for users objects ?**

Answer (score 0):

Correct or not, just make sure you're not leaking the user object in app logs. You may want to have another table though just to link users and passwords instead of having it all in the users object.